# Angular Error assigning “*” to a var declared in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I declared in the scope the var:

```
$scope.submit = {
  next:"",
  formparams:"",
  value:""
};
```

In my HTML I have:

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="opcion in menu.opciones">
    <label> Opcion: </label>
    <input id="{{opcion.opcion}}" type="radio" name=grupo
          value="{{opcion.Submit}}+{{opcion.opcion}}" ng-model="submit.next"
          ng-change="submit.value={{opcion.opcion}}" ng-required="true"required> {{opcion.opcion}}                          
    </input>
  </div>
</div>
```

The array of options contains something like `{1,2,3,*}`.

When I select, every numeric option is working fine, but when I select the "*" in the console of the browser, the following error appears:

```
    angular.js:9419 TypeError: a is not a function
at OPERATORS.* (http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:9515:44)
at http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:10041:35
at Scope.$eval (http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:11961:28)
at http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:16943:13
at http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:16784:11
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:303:11)
at $setViewValue (http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:16782:7)
at http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:16284:14
at Scope.$eval (http://192.168.0.3:8080/MobilTest/lib/angular.js:11961:28)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:9419(anonymous function) @ angular.js:6843(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16786forEach @ angular.js:303$setViewValue @ angular.js:16782(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16284Scope.$eval @ angular.js:11961Scope.$apply @ angular.js:12061(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16283(anonymous function) @ angular.js:2613forEach @ angular.js:310eventHandler @ angular.js:2612
```

And the var is empty.

Comment: _the array of options contains something like {1,2,3,*}_. This is not an _array_. To make it an array use `[1, 2, 3, '*']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `{1,2,3,*}` `*` is being evaluated as an operator when combined with `+` in the expression `{{opcion.Submit}}+{{opcion.opcion}}`. Just change it to a character like so `{1,2,3,'*'}` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks, @Shaunak, you are rigth , the * was taken as a operator no a string value.